# Why running queries one by one yields correct results, but running lots of them in one chunk doesn't?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I create a simple table and a stored function to populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(255)
)//

CREATE FUNCTION populateIfNotAlreadyIn (idArg INT, valArg VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE alreadyIn INT;
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO alreadyIn FROM t WHERE id = idArg;
    IF alreadyIn <> 0 THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO t (id, val) VALUES (idArg, valArg);
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END//
```

Of course, the intended behaviour is that the function returns `0` if a row with the given ID already exists in the table, and `1` if it doesn't (in the latter case, the function also inserts such a row).

So now testing comes.

If I run testing queries in phpmyadmin one by one like that:

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(1, 'val1');
```

//Go//

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(2, 'val2');
```

//Go//

```
… etc
```

Then apparently, the results are correct: the function returns `1` and inserts a row if and only if there is no row with such an id in the table, otherwise it returns `0`.

So far, so good. But instead of running queries one by one, let's feed phpmyadmin with all of them at once. To be more specific, let's insert into phpmyadmin sth like this:

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(1, 'val1');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(2, 'val2');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(3, 'val3');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(4, 'val4');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(5, 'val5');
```

And then click `Go`, to run all of them.

Result? The rows are inserted correctly into table `t`. But the stored function returns incorrect values. Each call except the last one returns a `0`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @davidstrachan Why would I want to do what?

Comment: Why are you using phpmyadmin which is for admin to run multiple calls to a function?

Comment: @davidstrachan I wanted to quickly populate the database to test other, more complicated stored programs.

Comment: Use a data generator [**such as**](http://www.generatedata.com/). Set id as auto incremental

Comment: @davidstrachan Right, but since according to the design the stored procedure is meant to be used to populate the database, I thought I'd use this stored procedure as well (and am concerned with the wrong results...). Ofc a data generator might be a good idea, sadly ID can't be auto incremental though, as what I posted is ofc only a very simplified version

Comment: Your last point. You can generate auto increment id with program.In your case only val field is required id is set by Radio button for auto increment.  Your first point phpmyadmin is not designed for what you require. Run your stored procedures with PHP.